# Working With Multiple WSDLs Best Practices

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl.exe

I have a requirement of creating a Web Service interface using multiple existing WSDLs files having different namespaces. Some of the methods parameters in these WSDL have common name e.g. userID is used as parameter in multiple methods/operations.

I tried generating proxy classes for each file and then manually copy pasting required methods web service project. Using IntelliJ Axis2 resulted WSDL definition differs from actual WSDLs definition e.g. userID parameter gets renamed as userID0 and UserID1. Using visual studio (wsld.exe) resulted WSDLs definitions are close match of actual WSDL definition but when I deploy service on server parameters always received null may be due namespaces issue.

I was just wondering if some one can guide me what are the best practice/way of creating a single web service interface from multiple existing WSDLs having same definitions as of original WSDLs.

Comment: What do you mean multiple wdsl? All i know is one webservice can be access by mutiple clients.

Comment: I have to integrate our service with external system.The company responsible for the external system have provided us multiple WSDL. Each WSDL file contains information about various services  about the types used for each service.

Comment: WDSL means it a web service.. if it is multiple as you've said, it would be a  different functionality am i ryt?

Comment: functionality is different but belongs to same system. Each WSDL file contains functions of a module  e.g. customer, Employee, Accounts etc.

Comment: Then what would you do to that multiple WSDL you've said.. you are going to use its function inside of it?

Comment: External system integration requires single web service interface using methods from these WSDL files. What I am try to do here is to create proxy classes of each WSDL and then copy required methods in empty web service project to expose it as web service.

Comment: I agreed to your first solution you've said, if you can open it (WSDL file) then go ahead. good luck.. may i ask one thing, what language your wsdl made of? c#,java?

Comment: Don't have any clue. However, I am trying to create proxy classes in both Java and C#.

Comment: Ok man, good luck hope you can do it.